# Scrapy xpath get text of an element that starts with <

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to get text "<1 hour" from this html snippet.

```
<div class="details_wrapper">
<div class="detail">
    <b>Recommended length of visit:</b>
    <1 hour
</div>
<div class="detail">
    <b>Fee:</b>
    No
</div>
</div>
```

This is the xpath expression that I am using:

```
visit_length = response.xpath(
    "//div[@class='details_wrapper']/"
    "div[@class='detail']/b[contains(text(), "
    "'Recommended length of visit:')]/parent::div/text()"
).extract()
```

But it is not able to get the text. I think this is due to the "<" in the text that I need, it is being considered as a html tag. How can I scrape the text "<1 hour" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that Scrapy uses `lxml` under the hood, it might worth inspecting how `lxml` handles this kind of HTML, which contains XML special character `<` in one of the text nodes :

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> raw = '''<div class="details_wrapper">
... <div class="detail">
...     <b>Recommended length of visit:</b>
...     <1 hour
... </div>
... <div class="detail">
...     <b>Fee:</b>
...     No
... </div>
... </div>'''
... 
>>> root = html.fromstring(raw)
>>> print html.tostring(root)
<div class="details_wrapper">
<div class="detail">
    <b>Recommended length of visit:</b>

<div class="detail">
    <b>Fee:</b>
    No
</div>
</div></div>
```

Notice in the above demo, as you suspected, text node `'<1 hour'` is gone completely from the `root` element source. As a workaround, consider using `BeautifulSoup` since it is more reasonable in handling this HTML case (you can pass `response.body_as_unicode()` to create the `soup` from Scrapy response) :

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(raw, "html.parser")
>>> print soup.prettify()
<div class="details_wrapper">
 <div class="detail">
  <b>
   Recommended length of visit:
  </b>
  &lt;1 hour
 </div>
 <div class="detail">
  <b>
   Fee:
  </b>
  No
 </div>
</div>
```

Finding the target text node using BS can be done as follow :

```
>>> soup.find('b', text='Recommended length of visit:').next_sibling
u'\n    <1 hour\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a `lxml` issue, as already reported on `scrapy` parser `Parsel`, check here [the issue](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/issues/23).

As it says in there, a solution would be to pass the `type='xml'` argument to a selector, your spider should be something like this:

```
from scrapy import Selector
...
...
    def your_parse_method(self, response):
        sel = Selector(text=response.body_as_unicode(), type='xml')
        # now use "sel" instead of response for getting xpath info
        ...
        visit_length = sel.xpath("//div[@class='details_wrapper']/"
            "div[@class='detail']/b[contains(text(), "
            "'Recommended length of visit:')]/parent::div/text()").extract()
```

Comment: Close enough ! Thanks ! But the output is 1 hour instead of <1 hour.

Comment: yeah it removes those characters